# Python Json Parsing Key Value Filtering

Tags: python, json

How can I only get the lines which do not have `"popup:"` in them?

`json_data = json.loads(raw_json, strict=False)`

This is the data:

```
{
    "259655": { "params": ["OIL", "9,5"], "availability": "1", "reload": ""}, 
    "259656": { "params": ["OIL", "10"], "availability": "1", "reload": ""}, 
    "259659": { "params": ["OIL", "11,5"], "availability": "1", "reload": ""} , 
    "259661": { "params": ["SALT", "5"], "availability": "1", "reload": "", "popup": "" }, 
    "259662": { "params": ["SALT", "5,5"], "availability": "1", "reload": "", "popup": "" }, 
    "259663": { "params": ["SALT", "6"], "availability": "1", "reload": "", "popup": "" },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using dict comprehension to create a new dict without values that contain "popup" keys

```
filtered_dict = {i: json_data[i] for i in json_data if "popup" not in json_data[i]}
```